# Ruby regex for finding comments?

Tags: ruby, regex

I've been at this all day and I can't figure it out. I have some Ruby code in a string below and would only only like to match lines with code on them and the first comment for the code if it exists.

```
# Some ignored comment.
1 + 1 # Simple math (this comment would be collected) # ignored 
# ignored

user = User.new
user.name = "Ryan" # Setting an attribute # Another ignored comment
```

And this would capture:

1. 1. `"1 + 1"`
   2. `"Simple math"`
2. 1. `"user = User.new"`
   2. `nil`
3. 1. `"user.name = "Ryan"`
   2. `"Setting an attribute"`

I'm using `/^\x20*(.+)\x20*(#\x20*.+\x20*){1}$/` to match against each line but it doesn't seem to work for all code.

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but I'm pretty sure `# Simple math (this comment would be collected) # ignored` is only one comment, not two. The second `#` is treated literally because it's already commented out by the first `#`.

Comment: I know, this is the functionality I need.

Comment: This may be extremely difficult to not-possible. Consider a line like `user = "We're #1 \" #_# " # comment` , not to mention inline comments (like `i = 1 + /*comment */ 1`, if ruby has these). If you need something strong, use a parser (though that might ignore new-lines).

Comment: I have a solution. I'm using a library that can output the source code of a block of code. I can output the source code without comments and with comments so I can just remove everything that isn't a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the underlying problem is quite difficult, you can find what you need here using the pattern:

```
^[\t ]*[^\s#][^#\n\r]*#([^#\n\r]*)
```

Which reads:

- `[\t ]*` - leading spaces.
- `[^\s#]` - one actual character. This should match the code.
- `[^#\n\r]*` - Characters until the # sign. Anything besides hash or newlines.
- `#([^#\n\r]*)` -  The "first" comment, captured in group 1.

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/wNJTMDV9Bw

Answer (score 5):

Kobi's answer partially works, but does not match lines of code that lack a comment at the end.

It will also fail when it encounters string interpolation, e.g.:

```
str = "My name is #{first_name} #{last_name}" # first comment
```

...will be erroneously matched as: `str = "My name is #{first_name}`

**You need a more comprehensive regex.**  Here's one idea:

```
/^[\t ]*([^#"'\r\n]("(\\"|[^"])*"|'(\\'|[^'])*'|[^#\n\r])*)(#([^#\r\n]*))?/
```

- `^[\t ]*` - Leading whitespace.
- `([^#"'\r\n]("(\\"|[^"])*"|'(\\'|[^'])*'|[^#\n\r])*)` - Matches a line of code.
  Breakdown:

  - `[^#"'\r\n]` - the first character in a line of code, and...
  - `"(\\"|[^"])*"` - a double-quoted string, or...
  - `'(\\'|[^'])*'` - a single-quoted string, or...
  - `[^#\n\r]` - any other character outside a quoted string that is not a `#` or line ending.
- `(#([^#\r\n]*))?` - Matches first comment at the end of a line of code, if any.

Due to the more complex logic, this will capture 6 subpatterns for each match. Subpattern 1 is the code, subpattern 6 is the comment, and you can ignore the others.

Given the following block of code:

```
# Some ignored comment.
1 + 1 # Simple math (this comment would be collected) # ignored 
# ignored

user = User.new
user.name = "Ryan #{last_name}" # Setting an attribute # Another ignored comment
```

The above regex would produce the following (I excluded subpatterns 2, 3, 4, 5 for brevity):

1. 1. `1 + 1`
   6. `Simple math (this comment would be collected)`
2. 1. `user = User.new`
   6.
3. 1. `user.name = "Ryan #{last_name}"`
   6. `Setting an attribute`

Demo:  http://rubular.com/r/yKxEazjNPC