# Parse Ruby file for comments

Tags: ruby, comments

I want something that can parse a ruby file to give me the file positions of comments. Ranked by desirability:

1. Ideally, there would be some command-line arg I could pass to "ruby" since of course "ruby" would know. But there doesn't seem to be one for this?
2. Does anyone know if/where in "ruby" I could hook in and use its methods to know where the comments are?
3. Some well-known regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, get us some input and expected output and maybe some code you tried. You can read this article to improve your answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The input is any ruby file with comments. The output can be of any form as long as I can derive the file positions of comments. I naively started with a regexp like /\#.*/ but quickly realized it was more complicated than that (e.g. a hashtag embedded in a string). I am hoping, and will research later, that I can hook into the "ruby" executable since who should know best, right? Else I will try to adapt the regexp from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865371/ruby-regex-for-finding-comments

Comment: How does one determine what an "off-site resource" is? The how-to-ask link doesn't mention it.

Comment: The [_on-topic_ help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) prohibits reqeusts for "a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource."  That's all it says, so if that's not clear, then I'd ask for clarification on meta.  That would be the first step to getting the help page improved.

Comment: Clue to how complex Ruby comments can be, so regexp will never be able to cover all cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989762/multi-line-comments-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/ext/ripper

Example:

```
require 'ripper'
require 'pp'

class CommentRipper < Ripper::SexpBuilder
    def on_comment(token)
        super.tap { |result| pp result }
    end
end

contents = File.read("file.rb")
pp CommentRipper.new(contents).parse
```

Helped me understand Ripper better: http://svenfuchs.com/2009/7/5/using-ruby-1-9-ripper